# show column for each type with PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

How to display one column for each type with foreach and if with php

```
       @foreach ($detalles as $det)
                <tr>
                   if($det->inventariable == 1){
                   <td><font size="2">{{$det->cantidad}}</td>
                </tr>
                  } 
                  <tr>
                   if($det->inventariable == 2){
                   <td><font size="2">{{$det->cantidad1}}</td>
                  </tr>
                  }
                  <tr>
                   if($det->inventariable == 3){
                   <td><font size="2">{{$det->cantidad2}}</td>
                  </tr>
                   }
            @endforeach
```

Comment: The control structures used are not standard PHP syntax. Are you using a templating library, such as blade? Please also post sample data in the source data structure, together with expected output.

Comment: yes i'm occupying laravel

Comment: I have 3 types of products, each one has quantity, quantity 1 and quantity 2. When any of them is 0, it is not displayed

Comment: Please post an actual data sample with the expected output. We can then avoid going back and forth clarifying what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
@foreach ($detalles as $det)
            <tr>
               @if($det->inventariable == 1)
                 <td><font size="2">{{$det->cantidad}}</td>
                 <td><font size="2"></td>
                 <td><font size="2"></td>

               @elseif($det->inventariable == 2)
                  <td><font size="2"></td>
                  <td><font size="2">{{$det->cantidad1}}</td>
                  <td><font size="2"></td>
        
               @elseif($det->inventariable == 3)
                   <td><font size="2"></td>
                   <td><font size="2"></td>
                   <td><font size="2">{{$det->cantidad2}}</td>
               @endif
            </tr>
        @endforeach
```